# Login problem on: Firefox → math.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, login, firefox, security

I'm now using Firefox 31.

I'm connected on many stackexchange web servers with the same login method.
Unfortunately I can't connect within the exact same session, with the same browser, and with the same authentication method on:

```
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/login
```

When I click here: [image: math.stackexchange login window]

nothing happens. Moreover, if I open Firebug console, I can see (only on the authentication window from math.stackexchange.com), the following error message:
[image: Firebug security error]

How may I investigate any further this security error
detected within Firefox and this web server?

Comment: Exaclty same problem here. Firefox 31 on Maverick.

Comment: Same with Stack Overflow on Firefox 31/Win7. Only www.stackoverflow.com, as of course I'm logged in to meta to post this comment.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on an vanilla installation of Firefox version `Firefox Quantum 64.0` with `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]`, you can by pass this problem if you go first to https://www.google.com/ and login. Only then, you can access https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login and when you click on the google login button, it will work.