# Pasting code and undoing undo much more than expected

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, editor

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. Like this:
   [image]

Once, I read somewhere (hence, this is may be a duplicate post, but I cannot find no one else reporting it right now) this problem is because when you paste something on StackExchange sites, an entry on the undo list is not created for the pasted item, then, when undoing the last thing, it will undo the pasted item and some other things you did before, i.e., the last undo event on the stack.

Other sites I use as GitHub, does not have such problem. This undo thing problem has become extremely annoying after years using StackExchange sites. I never seem anything close to this behavior anywhere else in the world so far. If you know something else which also has this "feature", please, comment.

I am not sure if this is a bug or if it is like this by design. If it is by design because someone which works on StackExchanges likes it (I am definitely not sure why they like it), then, this post would be a feature request for an user's setting, allowing us to change this really "awesome" feature.

In case someone thinks I am trolling, here is a video reproducing the problem:

[image]

If you need more detailed instructions, videos or tutorials about how to reproduce this awesome "feature", please, do not hesitate to ask!

Here, I am using Google Chrome: `Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

If you think GitHub is also bugged/broken like this, here is another video showing you I am not trolling and GitHub works wonderfully:

[image]

#### Expected Behavior

More fiercely, using the GitHub interface, let us call the next video as an expected behavior for StackExchange websites editor:

[image]

#### Actual Behavior

Re-posting here again, the Actual Behavior of StackExchange Websites, so you can closely compare both, **Expected Behavior** versus **Actual Behavior**:

[image]

Comment: OS and browser configuration, please? Also, have you tested this on other sites? It may be that SE uses the system's undo feature while GitHub implements their own; test on other non-SE sites and check if it's still an issue.

Comment: My OS: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]`, I am not sure how to give you browser configurations. Anyways, instead of giving thousands of lines, I just installed a vanilla Firefox version `Firefox Quantum 64.0` and I can also reproduce the problem on it. So, if you want the same configuration, just install a vanilla `Firefox Quantum 64.0`. If you want to do exactly as I did, you also need to login on StackExchange using a Google Account.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, if you try to login with Google on `Firefox Quantum 64.0`, by accessing this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login it does not work. You have to first go to https://www.google.com/ and login first. Only then, you can access https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login

Comment: Report a new bug for that, please.

Comment: It is already reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238208/login-problem-on-firefox-%E2%86%92-math-stackexchange-com for an older version of Firefox.

Comment: In that case, follow the steps [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without) to draw attention to it.

Comment: I've just ignored this for a while but it's definitely a problem and I don't think it's limited to pasting. How much undo removes is pretty arbitrary, which is why I stopped using it.

Comment: Why the hate for the Pyton. language?

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/editors-undo-does-not-track-pastes, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203193/cut-paste-are-not-considered-undoable-operations, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258639/undo-feature-in-se-web-markdown-editor-is-exhibiting-unexpected-behavior-in-safa

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, hit Ctrl-Z then Ctrl-Shift-Z, so undo then redo, that makes it work.

at least works on Windows 8...

redo makes small redos, so basically 1-0.5=0.5 so that will make a half of 1 undo.

Comment: Thanks, I had used this technique a long time ago, but I had completely forgot about this. Instead of manually doing this, I would prefer to create same browser extension or script which detects the StackExchange editor and does this automatically.

Comment: @user Your welcome, happy to help, please accept tho :-), and up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

If you type a large bit of code without pausing at all, hitting undo will undo the entire section of code you just typed. However, if you pause for a few seconds while you're writing the code, it should only undo the section after you paused. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but that's how it works on my computer and browser.

Comment: Why is this? It seems different to how a lot of other sites/applications work (where they'll undo one character/action at a time, rather than a small chunk). Is there a way to coerce SO to use the 'one character at a time' convention used elsewhere?